# Using Left & Full Outer Joins Together

Tags: sql

[Simplfying my tables] I have an excel model that outputs a forecast based on clients orders aggregated by month.
Table A

```
+----------+--------+----------+
| Customer | Volume |   Date   |
+----------+--------+----------+
| A        |    100 | 1/1/2020 |
| B        |    100 | 1/1/2020 |
| C        |    100 | 1/1/2020 |
| A        |    100 | 2/1/2020 |
| B        |    100 | 2/1/2020 |
| C        |    100 | 2/1/2020 |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

I want to join this data to live data coming from a database that is aggregated monthly by first date as well (i.e. if customer orders on 1/5/20 = 1/1/2020). Table B:

```
+----------+--------+----------+
| Customer | Volume |   Date   |
+----------+--------+----------+
| A        |    100 | 1/1/2020 |
| A        |    100 | 1/1/2020 |
| A        |    100 | 1/1/2020 |
| B        |    100 | 2/1/2020 |
| B        |    100 | 2/1/2020 |
| Z        |    10  | 2/1/2020 |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

I also have a third table that only has the Customer's first order date: Table C:

```
+----------+----------+--+
| Customer |   Date   |  |
+----------+----------+--+
| A        | 1/1/2020 |  |
| B        | 1/1/2020 |  |
| C        | 1/1/2020 |  |
| Z        | 2/1/2020 |  |
+----------+----------+--+
```

I want to compare how the forecast (A) is tracking against the live data coming in (B), as well as add in the Customer's first Order Date (C). Since (B) is the most granular data, I am starting with this as my base. If I do a left join to (A) and (C) then some of Table A gets cut off (which I do not want); however my Table (C) data comes in correctly. If I do a full outer join to (A) then I do get the total forecast coming in correctly but the full outer join messes up Table (C). To add more complexity, Table B might have additional customers that were not part of the forecast so I need to see this data as well.

Forecast Number cut off:

```
select 
 b.customer,
 b.volume,
 b.date,
 a.volume,
 c.date
from b
left join a on b.customer = a.customer
left join c on c.customer = b.customer
```

Incorrect Data:

```
select 
     b.customer,
     b.volume,
     b.date,
     a.volume,
     c.date
    from b
    full outer join a on b.customer = a.customer
    left join c on c.customer = b.customer
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: What do you mean by "messes up Table C"? What exactly is incorrect about it?

Comment: I would start by familiarising myself with the concept of a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, because MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN`.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Also, you haven't shown what results you want, which would help in answering the question.

Comment: @Bambatman . . . You also haven't explained anything about the date.

Comment: Please **edit the question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include an example of the results you're getting, plus the results you expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the coalesce function to join Table C with entries of both tables A and B:

```
select 
     coalesce(a.customer, b.customer),
     b.volume,
     b.date,
     a.volume,
     c.date
    from b
    full outer join a on b.customer = a.customer
    left join c on c.customer = COALESCE(b.customer, a.customer)
```